# Remove the suffix of spriteSheets image name

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-transcoder

I have the following job request for Transcoder API

```
  const request = {
    parent,
    job: {
      inputUri: `gs://${bucket}/${name}`,
      outputUri: `gs://${settings.bucket.cdn}/${fileName}/`,
      config: {
        pubsubDestination: {
          topic: `projects/${settings.project.id}/topics/${settings.pubsub.transcoder}`,
        },
        elementaryStreams: [
          {
            key: 'video-stream',
            videoStream: {
              h265: {
                heightPixels: 1080,
                widthPixels: 1920,
                bitrateBps: 12288000,
                frameRate: 60,
              },
            },
          },
        ],
        muxStreams: [
          {
            key: 'video',
            container: 'mp4',
            elementaryStreams: ['video-stream'],
          },
        ],
        spriteSheets: [
          {
            filePrefix: 'spritesheet',
            quality: 90,
            spriteWidthPixels: 360,
            interval: {
              seconds: 3,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  } satisfies protos.google.cloud.video.transcoder.v1.ICreateJobRequest
```

It works.

However, it generates unpredictable filenames, for example prefix `spritesheet` I get `spritesheet0000000000.jpeg`

Is it possible to fix the name without those numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the [`spritesheet`](https://cloud.google.com/transcoder/docs/reference/rest/v1/JobConfig#spritesheet) parameter, you can only specify the `file_prefix`.

From the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/transcoder/docs/reference/rest/v1/JobConfig#spritesheet:%7E:text=Each%20sprite%20sheet%20has%20an%20incremental%2010%2Ddigit%20zero%2Dpadded%20suffix%20starting%20from%200%20before%20the%20extension%2C%20such%20as%20sprite_sheet0000000123.jpeg.):

> Each sprite sheet has an incremental 10-digit zero-padded suffix starting from 0 before the extension, such as `sprite_sheet0000000123.jpeg.`

This is done to prevent file name collisions when there are multiple output files.

You can access files in Google Cloud Storage by using a prefix as shown in the [Listing objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects#client-libraries) documentation.

Comment: I understand perfectly the reason of the suffix. Thank you